# Convert date format to character string

Tags: sas

**I have** a column of format `DATETIME23.` like this:

```
14.02.2017 13:00:25
```

**I want** to conver it to a string, so later, i would be able to modern it, so, for example, the final version would look like:

`2017-02-14 13:00:25.000`

**Problem** occures, when i try to convert date to char format: in result i have a string of smth like `1802700293` - which is the number of seconds.

**I tried:**

`format date $23.0`

or

`date = put(date, $23.0)`

**P.S** This is nother try:

```
data a;
format d date9.;
d = '12jan2016'd;
dtms = cat(day(d),'-',month(d),'-',year(d),' 00:00:00.000');

/* если нужно обязательно двухзначные день и месяц, то такой колхоз:  */
if day(d) < 10 then dd=cat('0',put(day(d),$1.)); 
else ddday=put(day(d),$2.);
if month(d) < 10 then mm=cat('0',put(month(d),$1.)); 
else mm=put(month(d),$2.);
yyyy=put(year(d),$4.);
/*dtms2 = cat(dd,'-',mm,'-',yyyy,' 00:00:00.000');*/
dtms2 = cat(dd,'-',mm,'-',yyyy,' 00:00:00.000');
dtms = cat(day(d),'-',month(d),'-',year(d),' 00:00:00.000');
run;
```

**BUT**, abnormally, the `dtms2` concat destroys the zero in the month element

Comment: datetime23. format is 'ddmmmyy:hh:mm:ss.ss', which is different to your example.  Can you clarify please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your datetime is stored as a SAS datetime, just use the appropriate format :

```
data test ;
  dt = '09feb2017:13:53:26'dt ; /* specify a datetime constant */
  new_dt = put(dt,E8601DT23.3) ; /* ISO datetime format */
run ;
```

Output

```
     dt                new_dt

 1802267606    2017-02-09T13:53:26.000
```

If you need to replace the 'T' with a space, simply add a `translate` function around the `put()`.

Answer (score 0):

For your `dtms` solution you can use `put` and the `Z2.` format to keep the leading zero when you concatenate:

```
dtms = cat(day(d),'-', put(month(d),z2.),'-',year(d),' 00:00:00.000');
```

You should be able to just use `put(date, datetime23.)` for your problem though instead of `$23`, which is converting the number of seconds to a string with length 23. However, as a comment has mentioned `datetime23.` is not the format from your example.